# how to convert time field into string using linq sql?

Tags: linq

i am using linq to fetch the data and converting time field into string.

At that time if i have a value 11:00:00 in time field of sql server.

But i am getting "Jan  1 1900 11:00AM" at the time of converting to string.

Please provide me help to fetch only time part.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourDateTimeObject.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

Or as Mark Seemann suggested:

```
yourDateTimeObject.TimeOfDay.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the field is of type DateTime. You can use the [TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) property to get only the time part.

```
timeField.TimeOfDay
```